# chromiumOS emerge undefined reference to `std::__1::mutex::unlock()'

Tags: c++, linux, chromium

I'm writing an ebuild file which used on chromiumOS.

But when i try to compile my code, i found that i can't compile my program by "emerge xxx". It work normal when i use make directly.

I get the following error lines:

```
 smiTransfer.o: In function `lock_guard':
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__mutex_base:91: undefined reference to `std::__1::mutex::lock()'
smiTransfer.o: In function `threadsafe_queue<_RECT_IN_ENCODE_Q>::push(_RECT_IN_ENCODE_Q)':
/var/tmp/portage/app-misc/test-9999/work/test-9999/./ThreadSafeQueue.hpp:35: undefined reference to `std::__1::condition_variable::notify_one()'
smiTransfer.o: In function `~lock_guard':
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__mutex_base:97: undefined reference to `std::__1::mutex::unlock()'
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__mutex_base:97: undefined reference to `std::__1::mutex::unlock()'
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__mutex_base:97: undefined reference to `std::__1::mutex::unlock()'
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__mutex_base:97: undefined reference to `std::__1::mutex::unlock()'
smiTransfer.o: In function `lock_guard':
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__mutex_base:91: undefined reference to `std::__1::mutex::lock()'
smiTransfer.o: In function `~lock_guard':
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__mutex_base:97: undefined reference to `std::__1::mutex::unlock()'
smiTransfer.o: In function `lock_guard':
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__mutex_base:91: undefined reference to `std::__1::mutex::lock()'
smiTransfer.o: In function `~lock_guard':
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__mutex_base:97: undefined reference to `std::__1::mutex::unlock()'
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__mutex_base:97: undefined reference to `std::__1::mutex::unlock()'
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:43: x64/test] Error 1
* ERROR: app-misc/test-9999::chromiumos failed (compile phase):
*   emake failed
*
```

And this is my MAKEFILE:

```
...
LABRARYS := -lusb-1.0
CC := g++
CFLAGS += -g -Wall -O2
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11
CPPFLAGS := $(CFLAGS)
CPPFLAGS += $(addprefix -I,$(INCLUDES))
CPPFLAGS += -MMD
...
$(EXECUTABLE) : $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -o $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJS) -L$(LIBSDIR) $(LABRARYS) -lpthread
```

Thank you.